# why is this the answer to this riddle?

Tags: riddle

Entombed alive yet I survived

To glimpse once again at the sun

But legs to ground are shackled down

Curtailing all efforts to run

In body lies a dozen knives

My crown's sure to split and to smell

A robber's spear flew by my ear

Be thankful this ended so well

## I read this riddle online, the answer to it is:

> a rose

## but i can't understand why this is the answer, can anyone explain?

Comment: Is there some part that seems especially confusing?

Comment: yes, the sixth and seventh lines, Is the robber a bee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entombed alive yet I survived

> When you plant a rose seed in the ground, it’s “entombed alive” but it survives to become a rose

To glimpse once again at the sun

> When it grows up, a rose gets its energy from the sun

But legs to ground are shackled down

> Roses are rooted in the ground

Curtailing all efforts to run

> And can’t move/run

In body lies a dozen knives

> This references the thorns

My crown's sure to split and to smell

> This references the flower, which people like to smell

A robber's spear flew by my ear

> Potentially scissors, cutting the rose, or the spear of a bee’s sting ‘robbing’ the rose of its pollen?

Be thankful this ended so well

Comment: Good explanation. It isn't a great riddle though as it could equally apply to rot13(bgure nebzngvp sybjref, abg whfg gur ebfr)